# Ayuda con Cifrado TapCode en Java

Tags: java

de nuevo molestando y la primera publicacion no me convencio, ya le di varias vueltas y no le encuentro alguna solución. el programa es muy parecido al cifrado polybios, solo que no logro que el resultado salga en puntos, los 2 primeros puntos ya están realizados.
[image: y]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

aqui el codigo de avance

```
    public class Cifrado {

      public static void main(String[] args) {

        char [][] matriz = {
                        {'a','b','c','d','e',},
                        {'f','g','h','i','j'},
                        {'l','m','n','o','p'},
                        {'q','r','s','t','u'},
                        {'v','w','x','y','z'},};


         System.out.println("\t   ---------------------");
         System.out.println("\t  | *  CIFRADO TAPCODE * |");
         System.out.println("\t   ---------------------");
         Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

         System.out.println("Ingrese el Mensaje: ");
         String mensaje  = sc.nextLine();
         System.out.println("\nMatriz");
         Imprimir(matriz);
      System.out.print("\nCifrado: ");
      String [] cipher = Cifrar_TapCode(mensaje,matriz);
      sc.close();


      }

   public static void Imprimir(char [][] matriz){
      for(int i=0;i<matriz.length;i++){

         for(int j=0;j<matriz[i].length;j++){

            System.out.print(matriz[i][j]+" ");
         }
         System.out.println("");
      }
     }

   public static String [] Cifrar_TapCode(String mensaje, char [][] matriz ){

     String [] cipher = new String [mensaje.toCharArray().length];
     char [] msj =  mensaje.toCharArray();
     for(int h=0;h<msj.length;h++){
      for(int i=0;i<matriz.length;i++){ 
     for(int j=0;j<matriz[1].length;j++){
        if(matriz[i][j]== msj[h]){
           cipher[h]=Integer.toString(i)+Integer.toString(j);

           break;
        }   
     }
  }

     System.out.print(cipher[h]+" ");
    }
    return cipher;

 }
 }
```

Comment: Agrega el código completo para poder probarlo.

Comment: me dice que es mucho codogio y que agregue mas detalles, pero lo intentare

Comment: listo, algo mal puesto, pero soloa si me lo permitio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agrego método para imprimir en puntos:

```
    // recibe como parámetro el arreglo con los valores del cifrado
    public static  void imprimirPuntos(String[] cifrado){

        //se itera el arreglo
        for (int i = 0; i < cifrado.length; i++) {
            // se extrae el primero numero del valor en la posicion[i]
            int n1 = Integer.parseInt(cifrado[i].substring(0,1));
            // se extrae el segundo numero del valor en la posicion[i]
            int n2 = Integer.parseInt(cifrado[i].substring(1,2));

            // se imprimen puntos según el valor de n1
            for (int j = 0; j < n1; j++) {
                System.out.print(".");
            }
            // un espacio de separacion
            System.out.print(" ");
            // se imprimen puntos según el valor de n2
            for (int j = 0; j < n2; j++) {
                System.out.print(".");
            }
        }

    }
```

En el método main:

```
String [] cipher = Cifrar_TapCode(mensaje,matriz);
imprimirPuntos(cipher);
```

Comment: Te agradezco mucho, me trajo muchas vueltas, gracias